# Response time or response times

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, grammatical-number

Which is grammatical?

> 1. response time of multiple services
> 2. response times of multiple services

Answer (score 1):

Response time would be appropriate if you wanted to refer to the response time of all the services as a whole. For example:

> The response time of the services is 10s.

However, if you want to refer to multiple time instances or a time interval then use *response times*. For example:

> "Typical response times are 8 to 16 ms for black-white-black, or 2 to 6ms for grey-to-grey."

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the rest of the sentence.

- The average **response time of multiple services** were not in the acceptable range.
- The range of **response times of multiple services** was not acceptable.

Comment: Your first sentence should use 'was' not 'were'. You are talking about a single response time- the average.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more context would be welcome. With what you posted I'd go with "response times"

"The response times of our intranet and extranet services have improved by 10% over the last month."

"The response time of our intranet and extranet services is perceived as slow by most users."

Both work. It depends on the context, IMO.